# Azure Pipeline condition based on variable from previous task

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I have an Azure Pipeline with the following YAML and I want to run through the "JobB" Job based on the condition:

```
and(succeeded(), eq(dependencies.JobA.outputs['PSA.varBoolA'], 'true'))
```

However, I am getting an error:

> ##[error]Unrecognized value: 'dependencies'. Located at position 21 within expression: and(succeeded(), eq(dependencies.JobA.outputs['PSA.varBoolA'], 'true')).

I am assuming I will run into a similar issue once it gets to the following line in the Deploy stage:

```
and(succeeded(), eq(stageDependencies.StageA.JobA.outputs['PSA.varBoolA'], 'true'))
```

YAML File

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  varBoolA: true
  varBoolB: false

stages:
- stage: StageA
  jobs:
  - job: JobA
    displayName: JobA
    steps:
    - task: PowerShell@2
      displayName: "PS 1"
      name: PSA
      inputs:
        targetType: inline
        script: |

          echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=varBoolA;isOutput=true]true"
          echo "variable varBoolA ${{ variables.varBoolA }}"

  - job: JobB
    dependsOn: JobA
    displayName: JobB
    steps:
    - task: PowerShell@2
      condition: and(succeeded(), eq(dependencies.JobA.outputs['PSA.varBoolA'], 'true'))
      displayName: "PS 2"
      name: PSB
      inputs:
        targetType: inline
        script: |

          echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=varBoolB;isOutput=true]false"
          echo "variable varBoolB ${{ variables.varBoolB }}"

- stage: StageB
  dependsOn: StageA
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(stageDependencies.StageA.JobA.outputs['PSA.varBoolA'], 'true'))
  jobs:
    - job: JobC
      displayName: JobC
      steps:
      - task: PowerShell@2
        displayName: "PS 3"
        name: PSC
        inputs:
          targetType: inline
          script: |

            echo "Stage B"
```

Any help with this will be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi, any update, have you checked my answer? Does it answer your question?

Comment: @BowmanZhu-MSFT thank you for your answer, however, it doesn't quite work for what I am trying to do. I've just updated my question as I need to access the variable in another job and also another stage but now getting a specific error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out my problem, I had the conditions in the wrong places.

So I had to move the first condition under JobB instead of being under the task PSB, and I had to move the second condition under the StageB to being under JobC, and now it is working as I expect:

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  varBoolA: true
  varBoolB: false

stages:
- stage: StageA
  jobs:
  - job: JobA
    displayName: JobA
    steps:
    - task: PowerShell@2
      displayName: "PS 1"
      name: PSA
      inputs:
        targetType: inline
        script: |
          echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=varBoolA;isOutput=true]true"
          echo "variable varBoolA ${{ variables.varBoolA }}"
          echo "varBoolA $(varBoolA)"

  - job: JobB
    dependsOn: JobA
    displayName: JobB
    condition: and(succeeded(), eq(dependencies.JobA.outputs['PSA.varBoolA'], 'true'))
    steps:
    - task: PowerShell@2
      displayName: "PS 2"
      name: PSB
      inputs:
        targetType: inline
        script: |
          echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=varBoolB;isOutput=true]false"
          echo "variable varBoolB ${{ variables.varBoolB }}"
          echo "varBoolB $(varBoolB)"

- stage: StageB
  dependsOn: StageA
  jobs:
    - job: JobC
      displayName: JobC
      condition: eq(stageDependencies.StageA.JobA.outputs['PSA.varBoolA'], 'true')
      steps:
      - task: PowerShell@2
        displayName: "PS 3"
        name: PSC
        inputs:
          targetType: inline
          script: |
            echo "Stage B"
```

Comment: thank you, this helps me a lot! I use it to simulate 'trigger' with commit message contains some magic strings.

Answer (score -2):

Below YAML should achieve your requirements.

```
trigger:
- none

variables:
  xxx: testvalue1
steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
        #This is task 1. Set variable here.
        $test = "testvalue" 
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=xxx]$test"
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
        #This is task 2. Use variable here.
        if("$(xxx)" -eq "testvalue"){
            Write-Host "success"
        }else{
            Write-Host "failed"
        }
```

Let me know whether above can answer your question.